# How to call a PHP web API (JSON) from an Android application?

Tags: android, json, api

I am totally new in Android and now I got a project for which I have to make login function through that existing webAPI which takes and gives the response in JSON format. But I have no idea how to it, I saw multiple examples and also tried them out but they didn't work.

Parameters are email and password for login.

Comment: This is not easy - you need to know about SQL injection, XSS, and password hashing. Use a PHP library or a hosted service if you can.

Comment: login API is already made by PHP developer, I just have to make a login activity with two parameters 'email' and 'password' and parse them into JSON format which will be validated by that API(login API)@halfer

Comment: Search for "JSON Android curl", you should get plenty of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what is actually being asked but here are a few tips:

- For consuming APIs, take a look at [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). It's a pretty straight-forward and helpful library.
- For dealing with JSON data, I recommend [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). It converts your Java Objects to JSON and JSON to Java Objects as well!
- Both Retrofit and Gson can be used together. You only need to set Gson as the ConverterFactory of Retrofit and you're good to go.

Comment: @Gavriel Costa thanx!! for your suggestion, GSON LIBRARY actually worked for me .. there is a plugin called "GsonFormat" which directly converts json to model java class.